# GeoServer 2.21.1 tag on github inaccessible

Tags: git, geoserver

Usually tags can be downloaded using `git fetch -t`, but not for 2.21.1

The tag 2.21.1 does not belong to any branch, see: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/2.21.1.

At least the actual commit of 2.21.1 can be fetched using:

```
git fetch origin 6a17a2ee2607c4b578d0d7aa242d999ffa2d9500
```

When checking it out you end up with a detached head.

Everything works fine with tag `2.21.0`. Something wired happens with `2.21.1`.

Comment: Running `git fetch --tags` on my machine works as I expect and fetches tag 2.21.1. You will have to provide more details on your setup to see what is different on your machine. Running `git checkout <tag>` will lead you to a detached state HEAD as expected. Also : as currently written, your post is technically not a question. Can you please reword it, to explain what you want to reach ?

Comment: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/2.21.0 shows the exact same message (And I am not saying that is a problem, just in case).

Answer (score 0):

After several days of unsuccessful tries to update my repository I finally succeed with: `git fetch --all`.

Sorry, I was too confused by the warning message. So I learned: release tags are regularly off any branch. There is nothing wired on github. Instead my own repository was somehow cluttered.

Sorry for the confusion.